# ExpressJS Date & Time Freeze

Tags: node.js, express

I was trying to create a scheduler that runs every midnight using [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). But the scheduler never runs, so i wrote a function to get date and time from the server from an endpoint to see check the current date and time

```
baseUrl:port/v1/service/getDate
```

i used [dateformat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat), the response i get should looks like:

```
{
  date1: yyyy-MM-dd (current date),
  date2: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss (current date with time),
  date3: yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss+0000 (timestamp with timezone)
}
```

But instead whenever i hit the endpoint multiple times, i got the same result and not the current datetime. I think this is a problem with my code piece but i don't seem to know where the problem is.

My code piece:

```
const newDate =  dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
const newDateTime = dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss")
const timestamp = dateFormat(now, "isoDateTime")

router.route('/getDate').get((req,res) => {
  res.json({
    date1: newDate,
    date2: newDateTime,
    date3: timestamp,
  })
})
```

Comment: Try implementing it without `npm` packages; maybe it's an issue on their part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `now` is not changed in a route itself. I suppose you stored it like

```
const now = new Date()
```

and that's the case.
You need to request and format a current date right before `res.json` inside the route:

```
router.route('/getDate').get((req,res) => {
  const now = new Date()
  const newDate =  dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd")
  const newDateTime = dateFormat(now, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss")
  const timestamp = dateFormat(now, "isoDateTime")

  res.json({
    date1: newDate,
    date2: newDateTime,
    date3: timestamp,
  })
})
```

Comment: this actually worked, thank you. I can't believe i overlooked something like this